# Collision in Python

Tags: python, game-engine

I'm using the game engine and programming in Python. I have a mesh and I need only a part of it detect collisions, I mean only a vertex group of that mesh. How could I do this? I know how to detect collisions using the entire mesh.

Answer (score 3):

To enable collision for the **physics** to certain faces you have to create a collision object.

To do this, add a new lowpoly mesh object which recreates the part which has to collide. Or enter edit mode with your object selected, select the collision faces (easy with pressing <kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>B</kbd>), hit <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate and <kbd>RMB</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> to cancel translation. Then hit <kbd>P</kbd>*> Selection* to separate the selected faces to a new object.

Finally parent the display object to the collision object (select the display object and then the collision object, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>*> Object*).
Go to the game properties, set the collision object to invisible and the Physics Type of the display object to No Collision.

To detect collision with/for **logic bricks** you must also create an other collision object.